# How to count timestamp data from several tables and group by date?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 9 tables that each contain rows with a `created_at` timestamp. Example for `table_1`:

```
created_at           | item_id | ..
2020-01-01 14:00:20  | 5       |
2020-01-01 14:32:01  | 11      |
...
2020-01-03 09:00:07  | 7
```

I would like to create a summary view that counts the rows in each of the 9 tables per **date**. For a single table I could simply do

```
select
  t1.created_at::date ,
  count(*)
from
  table_1 t1
group by
  t1.created_at::date;
```

But I have 9 tables and the view should look like

```
date       | count_table_1 | count_table_2 | ..
2020-01-01 | 141           | 200           | ..
2020-01-02 | 0             | 179           |
```

Comment: UNION ALL the tables, GROUP BY the result. Or the other way.

Comment: It's almost certainly more efficient to just run 9 queries and put the data together in your application layer.

Answer (score 3):

You can select from queires and join them:

```
select dt, t1.cnt as t1_cnt, t2.cnt as t2_cnt, t3.cnt as t3_cnt, ...
from
 (select created_at::date as dt, count(*) as cnt from table1 group by created_at::date) t1
full outer join
 (select created_at::date as dt, count(*) as cnt from table2 group by created_at::date) t2
 using (dt)
full outer join
 (select created_at::date as dt, count(*) as cnt from table3 group by created_at::date) t3
 using (dt)
...
order by dt;
```

This will get you nulls where there is no entry. If you want zeroes instead use `COALESCE`: `select dt, coalesce(t1.cnt, 0) as t1_cnt, ...`.

Comment: You can actually simplify this by doing `select *`.